# Adding/Removing rows from a form. Resetting entire form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

These three functions all work on Chrome, but not IE or Firefox.  The first functions adds a cloned row. The second function removes a cloned row.  The third function resets the entire field.   All three are well commented. Does anything obvious stick out to you? I am baffled.

Could it have something to do with the cloned rows using ID's and not classes?

```
$(function () {
    $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
        var num     = $('.clonedInput').length, // Checks to see how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
            newNum  = new Number(num + 1),      // The numeric ID of the new input field being added, increasing by 1 each time
            newElem = $('#CloneRow' + num).clone().attr({'id': 'CloneRow' + newNum}).addClass('addedRow').fadeIn('slow'); // create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value

    /*  This is where we manipulate the name/id values of the input inside the new, cloned element
        Below are examples of what forms elements you can clone, but not the only ones.
        There are 2 basic structures below: one for an H2, and one for form elements.
        To make more, you can copy the one for form elements and simply update the classes for its label and input.
        Keep in mind that the .val() method is what clears the element when it gets cloned. Radio and checkboxes need .val([]) instead of .val('').
    */
        // Hour - select
        newElem.find('.input_hr').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_hour').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_hour').val('0');

        // Minute - select
        newElem.find('.input_min').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_min').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_min').val('0');

        // Activiy - text
        newElem.find('.input_act').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_act').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_act').val('');

        // Category - select
        newElem.find('.input_cat').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_cat').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_cat').val('');

    // Insert the new element after the last "duplicatable" input field
        $('#CloneRow' + num).after(newElem);
        $('#ID' + newNum + '_title').focus();

    // Enable the "remove" button. This only shows once you have a duplicated section.
        $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', false);

    // Right now you can only add 13 sections, for a total of 15. Change '13' below to the max number of sections you want to allow.
        if (newNum == 20)
        $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', true).prop('value', "That's all, folks!"); // value here updates the text in the 'add' button when the limit is reached
    });

    $('#btnDel').click(function () {
    // Confirmation dialog box. Works on all desktop browsers and iPhone.
        // if (confirm("Are you sure you wish to remove this section? This cannot be undone."))
            {
                var num = $('.clonedInput').length;
                // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
                $('#CloneRow' + num).slideUp('slow', function () {$(this).remove();
                // if only one element remains, disable the "remove" button
                    if (num -1 === 1)
                $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', true);
                // enable the "add" button
                $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', false).prop('value', "add section");});
            }
        return false; // Removes the last section you added
    });
    // Enable the "add" button
    $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', false);
    // Disable the "remove" button
    $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', true);
    // Reset the entire form
    $('#btnRes').click( function () {
    {
    // Confirmation dialog box. Works on all desktop browsers and iPhone.
        if (confirm("Do you really want to reset the form? All data will be lost."))
            {
                 document.getElementById("BudgetFormEng").reset();
                 $('.addedRow').remove();
                 $('#output').empty();

                              };
        return false;
    };});
```

I am not receiving any errors from IE or Firefox.

Comment: can we see the html as well?

Comment: can you post a working example with the html on jsfiddle or codepen? it would make the whole process a lot faster and simpler

Comment: here is a working codepen.  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bdJvgG   thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is that I am an idiot.  In my html I had `<button><span id="btnRes/btnAdd/btnDel"></span></button>`.  The code was working but you had to click directly on the glyphicon span and not the white space of the button.